# How to determine what replica set a Mongo database was part of

Tags: mongodb

If I have a replica set up an running called `davesReplSet`, I turn off my comuter and come back and start a Mongo instance with the `dbpath` matching one from the replication set I get a warning:

```
** WARNING: mongod started without --replSet yet 1 documents are present in local.system.replset
**          Restart with --replSet unless you are doing maintenance and  no other clients are connected.
**          The TTL collection monitor will not start because of this.
**
```

How do I determine what the correct name for the set was?  or what replica set it was running under?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to this instance using the shell

```
mongo <host>:<port>/local
```

Then, you can access the `system.replset` collection and find the replica set by issuing:

```
> use local
> db.system.replset.find({},{_id:1})
{ "_id" : "myReplSet" }
```

Comment: Cheers Mark, when I run that command though I get no response.  Just another `>` prompt.

Comment: Just run a find, then and make sure you are in the "local" database

Comment: `db.local.find({})` also just returns nothing.

Comment: That's not what I have written. I take the time to answer your question. Please be at least so kind to read it properly.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to follow your instruction "Just run a find", I thought that was what you meant.